# Finding Intellij Line Breakpoints which slow application (order of magnitude) on remote debugging

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I am on Intellij 2017.1  - Remote Debugging is slow with line breakpoints(I understand that method breakpoints will slow the execution).

> Is there a way to know which line breakpoint is slowing the debugger?

I am looking for a way other than brute force toggle all breakpoints one after other.

> Is it reasonable to say having a **conditional line breakpoint** or
>   **Evaluate and log** is much slower(magnitude of 2x or 3x) than regular line breakpoint?

When I turn off "Mute Breakpoints" for a couple of seconds, execution flow goes blazing fast.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way for now, please vote https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155206